# Weak convergence and infinite sum

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

Suppose that $\psi_n$ converges weakly to $\psi$ in a Hilbert space $H$. Assume further $\{\phi_k\}$ is an orthonormal sequence in $H$. Is it plausible that

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|\langle\psi_n-\psi,\phi_k\rangle _{H}|^2=0?$

In particular, we can assume $H=L^2[0,1]$, $\phi_k=\sqrt{2}\sin(k \pi x)$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $\phi_k$ are complete, i.e. span a dense subspace in $H$, by the [Parseval identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_identity) $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|\langle \psi_n-\psi,\phi_k\rangle_{H}|^2=\|\psi_n-\psi\|^2$. So the limit is $0$ if and only if $\psi_n$ converges to $\psi$ strongly. For weak convergence this is false. Take $\psi_n=\phi_n$, it converges weakly to $0$ like any orthonormal basis, but  your sequence will consist of all $1$'s.

And $\sqrt{2}\sin(k \pi x)$ are complete in $L^2[0,1]$ by the usual theorems about Fourier series.

Comment: Or using Bessel's inequality assuming strong convergence. For weak convergence?

Comment: Thank you so much, at least now I know this not true in general.